# Execlp - Path correction

Tags: c, linux, exec

I am trying to execute a file similar to:

```
./foo bar baz band
```

Where

```
executable = "foo"
path_executable =" bar baz band"
```

And I am using the snprintf to concatenate and then fork a process using execlp

```
snprintf(final_executable, sizeof final_executable, "%s%s%s","./",executable,path_executable);
snprintf(for_execlp, sizeof for_execlp,"%s%s","./",executable);
```

And this is what I have tried based on my previous knowledge.

I am not able to execute the application `foo` correctly.

```
execlp(for_execlp,for_execlp,path_executable, (char *)0);
```

Could you please tell me where the error is.. i'm stuck here!

[My complete Code](http://pastebin.com/vyrxWWLK).

On the command-line I need to execute  the following command:

```
./blackscholes 1 /parsec-3.0/pkgs/apps/blackscholes/run/in_10M.txt prices.txt
```

Comment: `path_executable =" bar baz band"` not understood,  Is it `path_executable ="bar/baz/band"` ??

Comment: No, they are the arguments for that application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are `final_executable` and `for_execlp`? You're passing `sizeof final_executable` as the size argument to `snprintf()`, but `final_executable` is probably a `char *`, so `sizeof` will evaluate to the size of the pointer, not the size of the available storage.

Are you checking the return value of the `snprintf()` calls?

Also, what does "not able to execute the application `foo` correctly" mean? If `execlp()` is failing, what is the return value?

---

UPDATE based on code at `http://pastebin.com/vyrxWWLK`:

Fine. So, from `main()`, you call the function `run_apps("blackscholes"," 1 /parsec-3.0/pkgs/apps/blackscholes/run/in_10M.txt prices.txt")`. In `run_apps()`, you create arrays for your strings, so `sizeof` is correct. You use `snprintf()` to write `"/parsec/parsec-3.0/pkgs/apps/blackscholes/inst/arm-linux.gcc/bin/"` into the `path_to_executable` array, and `chdir()` to that. Then you `snprintf()` the string `"./blackscholes 1 /parsec-3.0/pkgs/apps/blackscholes/run/in_10M.txt prices.txt"` into the `final_executable` array, *pointlessly*, then write the string `"./blackscholes"` into the `for_execpl` array, then call `execlp(for_execlp,for_execlp,path_executable, (char *)0);`, which expands to `execlp("./blackscholes","./blackscholes"," 1 /parsec-3.0/pkgs/apps/blackscholes/run/in_10M.txt prices.txt", NULL);`. Note that the first (and only) command-line argument is `" 1 /parsec-3.0/pkgs/apps/blackscholes/run/in_10M.txt prices.txt"`, is that what you intended?

*HOWEVER*, you aren't checking the return value for [`execlp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execlp.html), and you still haven't said what "not able to execute the application `foo` correctly" means to you... so while the likelihood is that your problem is as pointed out by Grijesh Chauhan, that you're simply using `execlp()` incorrectly. It is, however, possible that `execlp()` is actually failing, in which case you need to handle that potential error, which your code is not doing.

Comment: `final_executable` defines the way in which I execute it on `bash`,
`for_execlp` is `./foo`. 
`final_executable` is a character array.

Comment: What do you mean by checking for return value from snprintf. I printed the values of final_executable and for_execlp and they were correct.

Comment: @pistal : Elchonon;s need to know that is declarations of two `final_executable` and `for_execlp`. information is not complete in your question so that we can suggest you complete rectification.

Comment: Here is a complete example: `http://pastebin.com/vyrxWWLK` 

Excuse me for the delay.

Comment: Answer updated based on pasted code. (Still, though, code should have been inserted into question.)

Comment: @ElchononEdelson: Thank you for your detailed reply. To execute the application, in this case, blackscholes, I need to give on the commandline. `./blackscholes 1 /parsec-3.0/pkgs/apps/blackscholes/run/in_10M.txt prices.txt`

and that doesn't seem to be the case. that's the problem I've been incurring.

Comment: `1 /parsec-3.0/pkgs/apps/blackscholes/run/in_10M.txt prices.txt` is the only cmdline argument required.

Comment: Yes. Are you *absolutely* sure that you want all of that as one command-line argument? That's quite unusual. And again, I repeat: Is [`execlp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execlp.html) failing, or is the application failing after the [`execlp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execlp.html) succeeds?

Comment: I am sure I need all that as a cmdline argument. Can we switch to chat?